# Convection in stratified atmosphere

Tags: fluid-dynamics, atmospheric-science, stability, convection

In the stability analysis of stratified atmosphere in the presence of gravity, we consider a blob of atmosphere and perturb it (move it up by a small height $\Delta z$). Initially, the blob had the same density and pressure as its surrounding. After it moves up, It has different pressure and density than its surroundings. It is assumed that acoustic waves quickly equalize the pressure, but the density remains different. Why don't acoustic waves also balance the density? Is the effect of acoustic waves always to equalize pressure? By what mechanism at the microscopic level is the pressure equalized?

Comment: “*It is assumed that acoustic waves quickly equalize the pressure, but the density remains different.*” If you’re referring to a particular point in the literature, please give an exact quote and a citation so people can understand the context and assumptions of the model being used.